# Runtime of the following procedure

Tags: runtime-analysis

I want to calculate the runtime of the following code as a function of n:

```
sum = 0
i = 1
  while (i < n)
    j = 1
    while ( j < i)
      k = 1
      while ( k < ^2)
        sum = sum + 1
        k = k+ i*i
    j = j + 1
  i = i + 1
```

If understand correctly then `i` will run from `1` to `n` and `j` from `1` to `i` in each iteration and then `k` from `1` to until it reach `n^2`

$$\ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_i(n)\rfloor} i^2 $$

I'm not sure if the answer is correct because it wasn't accepted at all. So I guess something is missing?

EDIT:

I tried to work out an example:

$\ n = 5 $

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline i = 1 & j = 1 & k = 1,2,3,4,5,...,25 \\ \hline i = 2 & j = 1 & k = 1,5,9,13,17,21,25 \\ \hline  & j = 2 & k = 1,5,9,13,17,21,25 \\ \hline i = 3 & j = 1 & k = 1,10,19,28 \\ \hline & j = 2 & k = 1,10,19,28 \\ \hline & j = 3 & k = 1,10,19,28 \\ \hline i = 4 & j = 1 & k = 1,17,33 \\ \hline  & j = 2 & k = 1,17,33 \\ \hline  & .. &  \\ \hline  & .. &  \\ \hline  \end{array}

Comment: How did you get to $\log_i(n)$? Or $i^2$?

Comment: i figured $\ i^2 $ because of the most inner loop `k = k+ i*i` and $\ \log_i(n) $ also because of the most inner loop where k starts at 1 and then each iteration the next value is $\ k+i^2$ am I wrong?

Comment: *Why* though. Don't assume this is correct just because, it *has* to have an explanation. Try to think how many iterations exactly are done, and *how much work* is done in each iteration (hint: its simpler than what you have done). Maybe try to do an example or two to get the hang of it

Comment: Thanks. I've added my example of going through each iteration I can clearly see that it's not $\ log_i(n) $ and I think it may be $\ \lfloor \frac{n^2}{i^2} + 1 \rfloor $, is it correct?

Comment: Yes! Thats more like it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way I can express this function in terms of only n?

Comment: Of course, you will have to simplify the summations to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The innermost loop is executed $\dfrac{n^2}{i^2}$ times, roughly (from $1$ to $n^2$ by constant steps $i^2$). The middle loop invokes it about $i$ times, which gives us $\dfrac{n^2}{i}$. Finally, the outer loop runs from $i=1$ to $n$, giving the sum $n^2H_n$ (Harmonic number). This is $\Theta(n^2\log n)$.

Does it match the answer sheet ?

Comment: It is. Thank you!